# Autoload composer class not found

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Boa tarde!

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolver, to criando uma mini aplicação, usando o autoload do composer, mas não está funcionando, fica dando que a class não existe. Essa é minha estrutura:

```
├── app
    └── Conn
        └── Conn.php
└── vendor
    └── composer
    └── autoload.php
└── composer.json
└── index.php
└── README.md
```

Minha classe `Conn` ta assim:

```
<?php

namespace Lelvtex\Conec;

class Conn
{
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbsa;
    private $host;

    private $connon;
    private $conn;


    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbsa, $host)
    {
        $this->connect($user, $pass, $dbsa, $host);
    }


    //PRIVATE METHODS
    private function connect($user, $pass, $dbsa, $host)
    {
        $this->connon = false;
        $this->user = strip_tags(trim($user));
        $this->pass = strip_tags(trim($pass));
        $this->dbsa = strip_tags(trim($dbsa));
        $this->host = $host;


        try {
            if (!$this->connon) {
                $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbsa;
                $options = array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',);
                $this->conn = new \PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
                $this->connon = true;
                echo "Conectado com sucesso!";
            }
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

Meu `index` ta assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Livre e Leve</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Lelvtex\Conec\Conn;

$conn = new Conn('root', '', 'livreelevevtex', 'localhost');
var_dump($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu `autoload_psr4` ta assim:

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Lelvtex\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),
);
```

Meu `composer.json` ta assim:

```
{
    "name": "lucascar/livreelevevtex",
    "description": "Projeto de Teste para Livre e Leve vtex",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Lucas de Carvalho",
            "email": "contato@lucasdecarvalho.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Lelvtex\\" : "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

O erro que ta dando é esse:

> Fatal error: Class 'Lelvtex\Conec\Conn' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\projetos\livreelevevtex\index.php on line 13

Então, parece estar tudo ok, mas não sei o motivo de não funcionar...

Comment: namespace App\Conn;

Comment: Por que App\Conn, Jorge?

Comment: O composer mapeia o namespace ao path para o ficheiro

Comment: Pode explicar em uma resposta? No caso eu estou utilizando o autoload do composer.

Comment: Por favor coloque o composer.json

Comment: Jorge, coloquei na edição

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80349/discussion-between-jorge-costa-and-lucas-carvalho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha pergunta foi respondida pelo usuário @Jorge Costa no chat!

O Lucas Gauna também deu praticamente a mesma explicação.

> trocar o Conec do namespace (Classe conn) para o nome da pasta em
>   questão (CONN)

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, tente trocar o Conec do namespace (Classe conn) para o nome da pasta em questão (CONN). Não possuo o privilegio de comentar ainda.
O namespace precisa estar com o mesmo caminho, se não ele não encontra.

Comment: Vi o comentário do chat agora, é o mesmo que o meu. Por favor informe que já foi respondida a questão. Pelo outro usuário